# Show developer console in ubuntu touch browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Silly, simple question, but...

How the heck do you show the developer console in ubuntu touch's webbrowser-app?

Comment: This would be very useful with it being the only decent browser option currently in Touch. There is nothing in the browser settings to bring this feature up. It may be early in its lifrcycle, but with Thia phone for developer use, you would think you can get it up. Raise it in launchpad.